# Starting Glassfish from hudson

Tags: glassfish, hudson

I use Hudson for both CI and restart of Glassfish server. It's convenient as doesn't require ssh access.

The simple hudson job with shell command used to work:

```
 cd /opt/glassfish3/glassfish/bin;
./asadmin start-domain domain1;
```

But from some time (don't remember when) this works very strange: the job is hanging until the start procedure is finished and exits, there are no exceptions in log:

> [#|2011-09-07T02:36:06.280+0400|INFO|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1 (43) startup time : Felix (3,022ms), startup services(38,884ms), total(41,906ms)|#]

But the GF in fact isn't started! There is no such process in the system! So I have to do the same manually from ssh console... Seems the process for GF is finished as soon as the hudson job finishes.

Thanks, Anton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. There are some other ways, but the easiest one is very curios :). Just use the env variable:

```
BUILD_ID=dontKillMe
```

and that's all! This tells Jenkins not to finish processes, launched by this job.
As the plugin for setting these variables I use [Jenkins Environment Inject Plug-in](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)

Hope this will help anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Hudson's behavior changed wrt forking a process.
You can also start GlassFish in embedded mode (in-process): http://embedded-glassfish.java.net/nonav/apidocs/ , http://weblogs.java.net/blog/bhavanishankar/archive/2011/03/02/quick-introduction-embeddability-glassfish-open-source-edition-31
or using :

```
java -jar glassfish/modules/glassfish.jar
```

(note you can omit the domain name, if there's only one domain configured).

Comment: Thanks, Alexis. Java -jar... is a good thing, it outputs the log directly to hudson console, but this process is launched inside hudson and the job hangs on forever.. I found the solution, see below

Answer (score 0):

another way to solve the problem  is just add the below lines at the start of jenkins.

**java  -Dhudson.util.ProcessTreeKiller.disable=true -jar jenkins.war**